# JHipster Error release 2.23.0 With Gradle and mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, gradle, jhipster

After the project generation jhipster with mongodb gradle and then all other choices by default. I have an error on "embedmongo-spring" is not 1.50.0 but 1.3.1 and javax.persistence.AttributeConverter / Converter can not be resolved in the file JSR310PersitenceConverters.java.

Is this a generation bug or problem is between chair and keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fixed with https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2226

The gradle build used in invalid embedded mongo dependency. The correct one is 
`de.flapdoodle.embed`